# [arara]: subdirectories and `% arara --preamble <araraCommandFilename> <texFilename>` option

Tags: arara

**Background**:

All of my subsection `.tex` files are saved in subdirectories.

The top-level parent file is able to call them, and
the subsection `.tex` files are able to run standalone without it.

I path the top-level `.tex` file and all of my subsection `.tex` files
to a universal preamble, like so:

```
% root path:
\providecommand{\main}{.}
\input{\main/Subfiles/0-Preamble/0-Preamble.tex}  % Preamble [document configuration]

% ./Subfiles/1-Intro/00-titlePage:
\providecommand{\main}{../..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/0-Preamble/0-Preamble.tex}  % Preamble [document configuration]

% ./Subfiles/2-Main/zz-Conclusions/futureWork.tex:
\providecommand{\main}{../../..}
\input{\main/Subfiles/0-Preamble/0-Preamble.tex}  % Preamble [document configuration]
```

Thus, I use always use the same `\input` command,
and only ever change the `\main` command to include
the appropriate number of up-jumps to the root path.

**Issue**:

I'd like to be able to
path the top-level .tex file and all of my subsection .tex files
to arara commands also through the use of the
`% arara --preamble <araraCommandFilename> <texFilename>` option.

The example `--preamble` file was a little unclear
in the `arara` package documentation.

**Requested Resolution**:

Could someone provide:

• A MWE of a preamble with more than one preamble option
• A MWE of a .tex file call to it when it is in a different directory.

Also:

Is there any way to use `\main`
(or to create a pathing variable as I did with `\main`)
for use in an arara command?

Comment: What is unclear in the documentation? You have to provide a project configuration with the key as given in the docs, the preamble is to be seen as directives that will be prepended to the file's content.

Comment: @TeXnician : If I understand a little more than before, to make a universal (set of) arara preamble(s), the operator must make a separate arara configuration file -- it is not a `.tex` file, it is a `.araraconfig.yaml` file. --> If so, then: -->

Is it possible to write anything directly in the `.tex` file which will influence the path which `arara` searches to find the `.araraconfig.yaml` arara configuration file?

Comment: In docs, "File lookup" section, there is information, that config files are searched for in current working directory, or in global directory. I think that adding arbitrary path might be possible, but you should contact arara team about that. They are very friendly ;)

Comment: No, arara will always use the working directory and the home directory for looking up the configuration file. But there's a command-line option to specify the working directory in version 5, so you can use a fixed one. There's no way for the tex file to influence the configuration lookup. But I agree with Tomáš Kruliš about contacting :)

Comment: To close the loop, I listed it here: https://github.com/cereda/arara/issues/140